# Can durandaljs has more than one shell.js?

Tags: durandal, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

I have 3 SPAs within one bigger project written by DuraldalJS (called A). Can A has 3 shell.js to load for each SPA? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. You can create three files, e.g. shellA.js, shellB.js and shellC.js.

Per SPA you must create a server page, e.g. IndexA.html, IndexB.Html and IndexC.html.

You can create a global javascript settings object in each page:

```
  <script>
    var mySettings = mySettings || {};
    mySettings.entrance = 'viewmodels/shellA';
  </script>
  <script src="/js/requirejs/require.js" data-main="/app/main"></script>
```

In main.js you can configure your Durandal app like so:

```
var mySettings = mySettings || {};
app.setRoot(mySettings.entrance, 'entrance');
```